# Webpack not resolving babel or babel-loader installed globally

Tags: node.js, webpack, babeljs

I have been trying a new project and wanted to use webpack and modules to split code. I have installed npm followed by installing webpack as follows
`npm install -g webpack`

`npm install -g babel-cli babel-core babel-loader babel-presets-es2015`

Now in my project I have created a new config.js file containing below content.

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/js/app.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'dist/js/bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            }
        ]
    },

}
```

However, I always get an error saying 
`ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'babel-loader'`

In other words, how to make webpack resolve globally installed packages?

Comment: `npm i babel-loader --save-dev` ?

Comment: @releaseanp doing that creates node_modules locally and installs the package again.
However, these packages are already installed globally. How do I make use of that?

Comment: what is the extension of the files you are passing through the loader. anything besides JS (maybe JSX) ?

Comment: @realseanp only js as you could see in the config.js

Comment: Also, copying globally installed packages from `/usr/local/lib/node_modules` to `myproject/node_modules` work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At last got it going. Not sure if it is the right way. However,
this is how my project is setup and working. I suppose there should be a better way of setting presets for module loaders.

```
my-project
  src
    js
      entry.js
      module1.js
      module2.js
  dist
    index.html
    js
      bundle.js
```

Now, my current `config.js` setup is as shown below.

```
module.exports = {

    resolve: {
      fallback: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
    },
    resolveLoader: {
        fallback: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
    },
    entry: './src/js/app.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'dist/js/bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-preset-es2015']
                }
            }
        ]
    },

}
```

Comment: I tried to use this solution, but 'fallback is producing an error saying it is an unknown property on the object.